# More than one id bootstrap carousel

Tags: carousel

I have multiple carousels into one bootstrap page with thumbnail navigation. But only one thumbnail nav is working. I use this script http://www.bootply.com/79859

I know it's because #myCarousel is not unique but how do I fix this? Multiple times placing this script with another id is not very fancy

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
interval: 4000
});

// handles the carousel thumbnails
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
  var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
  var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
  id = parseInt(id);
  $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
  $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});

// when the carousel slides, auto update
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
  var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
  id = parseInt(id);
  $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
  $('[id=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: you could add a class say `class="mycarousel1"` and then use that in the JS, you will then only need 1 set of JS as you can refer to multiple elements with the same class

Comment: It doesn't mather of the class = mycarousel1 or mycarousel I still need to multiply the script

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an Id but use a class.

```
<div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs slider-thumbs">
```

instead of

```
<div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs">
```

for exemple.

You can try with this carousel : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-reviews-with-rating

You can create multiple carousel into one page and they works.